# IntelliJ: Grammar-Kit / BNF: how to recover from errors?

Tags: parsing, intellij-idea, bnf, intellij-plugin, grammar-kit

I am writing a Custom Language plugin for IntelliJ.

Here is a simplified example of the language. Note that the structure is recursive:

[image]

I have successfully implemented the FLEX and BNF files, but I'm not sure how to add error recovery. I've read about *RecoverWhile* and *pin* in Grammar-Kit's HOWTO, but I'm not sure how to apply them to my scenario.

I call the brown items above ("aaa", "ccc", etc...) "*items*".

I call the yellow ones ("bbb", "ddd", ...) "*properties*".

Each item has an *item name* (e.g. "aaa"), a single *property* (e.g. "bbb"), and can contain other items (e.g. "aaa" contains "ccc", "eeee", and "gg").

At the moment, the plugin doesn't behave well when an item is malformed. For example:

[image]

In this example, I would like the parser to "understand" that "ccc" is the name of an *item* with a missing property (e.g. by detecting a newline before the closing bracket).

I don't want the broken "ccc" *item* to influence the parsing of "eeee" (but I do want the PSI tree to have the elements of "ccc" that are present in the text, in this case - its name).

Here are the FLEX and BNF that I use:

FLEX:

```
CRLF= \n|\r|\r\n
WS=[\ \t\f]
WORD=[a-zA-Z0-9_#\-]+

%state EOF

%%
<YYINITIAL>    {WORD} { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return MyLangTypes.TYPE_FLEX_WORD; }
<YYINITIAL>    \[     { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return MyLangTypes.TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_SQUARE_BRACKET; }
<YYINITIAL>    \]     { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return MyLangTypes.TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_SQUARE_BRACKET; }
<YYINITIAL>    \{     { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return MyLangTypes.TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET; }
<YYINITIAL>    \}     { yybegin(YYINITIAL); return MyLangTypes.TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET; }
({CRLF}|{WS})+        { return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }
{WS}+                 { return TokenType.WHITE_SPACE; }
.                     { return TokenType.BAD_CHARACTER; }
```

BNF:

```
myLangFile ::= (item|COMMENT|CRLF)
item ::=
    itemName
    (TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_SQUARE_BRACKET itemProperty? TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_SQUARE_BRACKET?)?
    itemBody?
itemName ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD
itemProperty ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD
itemBody ::= TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET item* TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
```

Comment: Did you find the answer?

Comment: @IrinaRapoport kind of... I was able to get around it. I don't remember all the details as it's been a while but I posted an answer based on the final code I have now... hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I was eventually able to make it work like this:

```
myLangFile ::= (item|COMMENT|CRLF)
item ::=
    itemName
    itemProperties
    itemBody?
itemName ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD
itemProperties ::= TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_SQUARE_BRACKET [!TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_SQUARE_BRACKET itemProperty ((TYPE_FLEX_SEMICOLON itemProperty)|itemProperty)*] TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_SQUARE_BRACKET {
    pin(".*") = 1
}
itemProperty ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD TYPE_FLEX_EQUALS? itemPropertyValue? (TYPE_FLEX_EQUALS prv_swallowNextPropertyToPreventSyntaxErrors)?
private prv_swallowNextPropertyToPreventSyntaxErrors ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD
itemPropertyValue ::= TYPE_FLEX_WORD
itemBody ::= TYPE_FLEX_OPEN_CURLY_BRACKET item* TYPE_FLEX_CLOSE_CURLY_BRACKET
```

It's not perfect; for example, it allows to separate item properties with space (and not just with a semi-colon) but it does seem to solve the more important problem.

This may also be of interest: https://github.com/JetBrains/Grammar-Kit/blob/master/resources/messages/attributeDescriptions/recoverWhile.html